# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException returns when decrypting the credit card number

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encryption, cryptography

My Encryption method is:

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
private static final byte[] KEY = "StBet9834#$10BCy".getBytes();

private String encryptCreditCard(String ccNumber) {
    // do some encryption
    if (ccNumber == null || ccNumber.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        //return Base64.encodeBytes(c.doFinal(ccNumber.getBytes()));
        byte[] ccNumberBytes = ccNumber.getBytes();
        byte[] encCCNumber = c.doFinal(ccNumberBytes);
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encCCNumber));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

And I used below method to decrypt my credit card details:

```
public void decryptCreditCard() {
  Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
  try {
    String ccNumber = this.cardNumber;
    if (ccNumber == null || ccNumber.length() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] ccENCBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(ccNumber);
    byte[] ccDECBytes = c.doFinal(ccENCBytes);
    this.plainCardNumber = new String(ccDECBytes);
    this.last4CreditCard =             plainCardNumber.substring(this.plainCardNumber.length() - 4);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

And my test card number string is: 5123456789012346. While executing this line:

```
byte[] ccDECBytes = c.doFinal(ccENCBytes);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
  at stbet.model.core.CustomerAccount.decryptCreditCard(CustomerAccount.java:527)
```

What does this error indicate? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Added the encryption method.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure that `ccNumber` in the decryption method is the actual output of the encryption method?

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes the output value is same :(

Comment: I just tried your code and it should work. Does [this](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/fa611c84594af7f4ac31) complete code work for you? If it does then the problem lies somewhere between the encryption and decryption.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you for your valuable time. I was trying your code. I am using "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64" where as you're using util.Base64. Could this be the issue. (As our project uses that library) also the java version is 7.

Comment: No, it works the same way. I tried it and updated the gist. Please try it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, your code works great. But what is the issue in my code to fail?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on my system, Nomesh, which means there is something wrong with your I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Your ALGORITHM must denote cipher with padding: for example: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding.

And your String representation of the encoded message cannot loose the bytes. You are using defualt encoding for string so most likely UTF-8 which is not suitable. You need byte to byte mapping, so for example: "ISO-8859-1"

return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encCCNumber),"ISO-8859-1");

or simply Base64.encodeBase64String should do the job;

Comment: the String/bytes conversion must preserve the 'bytes'. See the full answer.

Comment: I tried your solution also. but still the error is same.

Comment: Although these are all good ideas, they should not lead to a `IllegalBlockSizeException`